# Error from react: "You may need an additional loader to handle the results of these loaders"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on 2 years old React.js project.  Whenever I start it, the project gives me this error:

```
 ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   return getFeed(parseDOM(feed, options));
| }
> export * as DomUtils from "domutils";
| // Old name for DomHandler
| export { DomHandler as DefaultHandler };
```

And My `package.json` file is

```json
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.15.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "b64-to-blob": "^1.2.19",
    "base64-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "canvasjs": "^1.8.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.11.1",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "glamor": "^2.20.40",
    "image-exists": "^1.1.0",
    "localizer": "^0.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "profile-picture": "git+https://github.com/dsalvagni/react-profile-picture.git",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
    "react-avatar-edit": "^0.8.3",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.24.1",
    "react-calendar": "^3.0.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.0.3",
    "react-daterange-picker": "^2.0.1",
    "react-debounce-input": "^3.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-donut": "^1.0.4",
    "react-donut-chart": "^1.1.8",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.6.2",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.5",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-newline-to-break": "^1.0.6",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.1",
    "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-svg-donut": "^0.1.7",
    "react-toastify": "^5.5.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "urls-checker": "^1.1.0",
    "validate-image-url": "^1.0.1
```

I want to run the project on my system. Here is the browser output that is coming on `localhost:3000`

[image: In browser display]

Comment: What `node v` this project used to run, try running this project in `node 16.x`

Comment: i am running this on  node v16.17.0

Comment: I'm suffering as well with this :-(

Comment: my issue is resolved this error was due to old packages used i removed that specific package and got running project